# Разделение методов API ASP.NET Core для разных компаний

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Существуют две компании и API, которое разрабатывалось для одной из них.
Необходимо адаптировать API для другой компании. Будут различаться некоторые модели, запросы и ответы для методов, методы аутентификации.
Такой API лучше реализовать одним решением или сделать копию для другой компании?

Думаю, что необходимо разрабатывать одним решением и ввести константу по которой можно будет переключаться между двумя компаниями. Будет 2 контекста БД, при необходимости можно будет отделить методы, которые требуют изменения для другой компании. Для каждой компании будет своя публикация.

Comment: Попробуйте создать новую версию вашего API,  для второй компании.  В этом [видео](https://youtu.be/jHlmvgyr4Rw),  показан способ загрузки библиотек для версионирования.

Comment: Версионирование в данном случае наверное не подходит по причине того, что это не новая версия API, а развитие уже существующей. Путь к методам API второй компании думаю выделить записью в пути обращения к методам

Comment: ИМХО, вопрос из разряда "как правильно кушать". Если методы общие, и все другое общее, то разделяйте при помощи ключа (доступа); если методы разные, то делайте отдельный API (условно `/api/team1/method` и `/api/team2/method`); если методы частично разные, то это уже другая версия одного API. Ну а разный проект - зависит от того, что в этом проекте, если там все совершенно разное и мешает работе первому, то выносите в отдельный, а если нет, то... смысл другого проекта? Вообще, странно видеть под каждую компанию свой API, обычно API делается под продукт, а не под персону, задумайтесь об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал чтобы они не были связаны между собой. Везде должно быть свое API.

Comment: В этом есть смысл, но будет много общих доработок и в случае такой реализации их придется прописывать сразу в двух проектах

Comment: @T0NI сделать общую сборку для обоих проектов?

Comment: @OwDafuq Можно, если под общей сборкой понимается вынос повторяющихся частей кода в отдельный проект и создание ещё одного проекта с API для другой компании в существующем решении

Comment: Ну, опять же, если у вас бизнес логика одинаковая - выносите её отдельно, а принимающие API отдельно, но ссылаться оба API будут на одну сборку с логикой. Но в целом - да, всё, что повторяется - в отдельный проект и переиспользуйте где нужно.